# Изменить выборочный символ при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
<span class="_ _179">
```

я хочу изменить `" "` на `' '`
Написал регулярное выражение

```
tag = re.sub(r'<span class="_ _\d{1,6}">', r'', str(tag))
```

что передать вторым параметром (на что меняем)?

я это вижу как то так

```
tag = re.sub(r'<span class="_ _\d{1,6}">', r'<span class='_ _числокотороенашлось'>', str(tag))
```

Но как это записать?

Comment: `я хочу изменить " " на ' '`, зачем это делать? Непонятно что на что вы хотите поменять. Вместо `<span class="_ _179">` что должно получиться?

Comment: @gil9red Я так понял должно получиться `<span class='_ _179'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в `re.sub` передавать функцию, через которую можно сделать замену всего встреченного выражения на новое

Пример:

```
import re


def on_match(m: re.Match) -> str:
    return f"<span class='{m.group(1)}'>"


text = '''<span class="_ _160">
<span class="_ _150">
<span class="_ _2">'''

new_text = re.sub(r'<span class="(_ _\d{1,6})">', on_match, text)
print()
print(new_text)
```

Еще можно сделать `on_match` без составления новой строки, меняя только  найденную:

```
def on_match(m: re.Match) -> str:
    return m.group().replace('"', "'")
```

Результат:

```
<span class='_ _160'>
<span class='_ _150'>
<span class='_ _2'>
```

Comment: А зачем функция, если есть банальный back reference? `re.sub(r'(<span class=)"(_ _\d{1,6})"(>)', r"\1'\2'\3", text)`

Comment: @GrAnd, хороший вариант, сделайте ответ, я вам плюс поставлю :)

Comment: Ок. Оформил как ответ. :)

Answer (score 3):

В регулярных выражениях есть возможность ссылаться на уже найденные группы (т.е. подставлять содержимое группы на место ссылки), так называемый `backreference` (они же обратные ссылки).

> You can match a previously captured group later within the same regex
> using a special metacharacter sequence called a backreference.
>
> \<n>
>
> Matches the contents of a previously captured group.
>
> Within a regex in Python, the sequence \<n>, where <n> is an integer
> from 1 to 99, matches the contents of the <n>th captured group.

Поэтому вся замена сводится к одной строчке:

```
tag = re.sub(r'(<span class=)"(_ _\d{1,6})"(>)', r"\1'\2'\3", tag)
```

Или более универсальный regexp где учитываются возможные пробелы в tag:

```
tag = re.sub(r'(<\s*span\s+class\s*=\s*)"(_ _\d{1,6})"(\s*>)', r"\1'\2'\3", tag)
```